# Plurals: finance, spending, receipts 

Tags: grammatical-number

My topic is money, budgeting and public finance(s?).

1. Do you say public finance or public finances? (like in http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/business/8573128.stm)
2. Budget has two sides, spending and receipts? Why is one singular and second plural?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, I believe that *finances* (plural) have to do with the funds of the government (i.e. the little gold we have left int the Treasury), whereas  public *finance* is the management of those funds.

If you type in "define: finance" on google, you get:

> Finance is the science of funds management.

whereas if you perform the same search on "finances", it outputs:

> funds: assets in the form of money

In response to your second question (spending vs. receipts, plurality),
[see the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Classification_of_nouns_in_English)  on classification of nouns. One could be considered non-concrete and one concrete, or perhaps one is uncountable and the other countable.

Hope that helps!